# Regarding direction of gradient of a function

Tags: optimization

I was reading this book related to optimizing a function f(x,y) with constraints g(x,y) = 0. The book says that let us suppose g(x,y) define a surface, then gradient of the g(x,y) will be orthogonal to the surface. But I am a bit confused how is it possible. I mean gradient always points in the direction of maximum increase. It is not necessary for it to be orthogonal.

For eg lets take the function

```
f(x) = x^2
```

If I take the gradient of the function at x=1, then its value is 2i with i giving the direction. This direction is not perpendicular to the function or its tangent at the point (1,f(1)).

I am a bit confused. So any clarifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function that you give is a function of $1$ variable only.  So there is only $1$ way that the function can increase at $x=1$.

Suppose we had, instead, $f(x,y)=x^2-y$.  This is the actual graph you are describing: $y=x^2$.  In particular, we are interested with the level curve $f(x,y)=0$.

This is now a function of two variables.  Now take the gradient $\nabla f=\langle2x,-1\rangle$, and at $(1,1)$, this becomes $\nabla f=\langle2,-1\rangle$.  Look where this graph is pointing!  It is perpendicular to the tangent line of the level curve $f(x,y)=0$.

Comment: Additional remark: if $f(x,y)=x^2$, the gradient $\langle 1,0\rangle$ is orthogonal to the line $x=1$, as claimed. (BTW notice that \ langle \ rangle make better angle brackets than inequality signs.)

Comment: I have fixed this.  Thank you for this $\langle \rangle$ tip.